# To draw horizontal line in tablix region

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I am using SSRS 2005(MS-BIDS 2005) to design reports.For designing one of the table i have a requirement to draw a horizontal lines above and below group headers and footers as shown in the image below

[image: report table]

When i try to drag and drop a line from the tool box, i get the below error

[image: error message]

Is there any way using which i can draw lines as shown in the image.

Thanks in advance :) .

Comment: Why overcomplicate things?  Your table has borders, use them instead of a line.

Comment: Thanks Kyzen for making me know.I am a newbie in SSRS and still need to explore lot of things in the tool.

Comment: @kyzen you should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use borders property. Make top and bottom **border style**  as **solid** in border style and rest as **None**. Then border color as Black do it where you want lines. And just set **border style** as **None** where you don't want it.